# Convergence of $ \sum_{i =0}^\infty i! \left( \frac{x}{i+1} \right)^i $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

One of my assignment questions was to find if the series $$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty S_i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty i!\left( \frac{x}{i+1} \right)^i $$ converges or diverges, using d'Alembert's ratio test and the logarithmic test (if $ l =\lim_{n\to 0} n \ln \frac{S_{n}}{S_{n+1}}$, the series converges if $ l > 1$ and diverges if $l < 1$).

I've determined that it converges if $ x < \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} $  and diverges if $ x > \frac{1}{\sqrt e} $, but when $ x = \frac{1}{\sqrt e} $, I get $ l = \lim_{n\to\infty} -(n + \frac{1}{2})$, which is always less than one, meaning the series is divergent. But this seems wrong to me (the value of $l$ that I got), and WolframAlpha fails to even tell if the series is convergent or divergent. Is this correct?

I also have a doubt that I got the actual summation wrong. The series was: $$ 1 + \frac{x}{2} + 2!\frac{x^2}{3^2} + 3!\frac{x^3}{4^3} ...$$ WolframAlpha also fails to find the general term of this series. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: I think the right inequality is $|x| > e^{-1}$ for this series to diverge.

Comment: By the way it can converge or can diverge when $x = e^{-1}$. A more complicated test is necessary to find out.

Comment: @TimurBakiev you're right! I accidentally cancelled out a square instead of a square root. And yeah, I was applying a more complex test, but got the answer wrong due to taking $ x = \frac{1}{\sqrt e} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_i=\frac{i!}{(i+1)^i}$$
radius of convergence is
$$r=\lim_{i\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_i}{a_{i+1}}\right|$$
that is
$$r=\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{\frac{i!}{(i+1)^i}}{\frac{(i+1)!}{(i+2)^{i+1}}}=\lim_{i\to\infty}\left(\frac{i+1}{i+2}\right)^{-i-1}=$$
substitute $i+1=n$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{-n}==\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}=e$$

Comment: Just like the root test.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty S_i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty i!( \frac{x}{i+1} )^i
$

Applying the n-th root test,
the term is
$(i!)^{1/i}( \frac{x}{i+1} )
\approx \frac{i}{e} \frac{x}{i+1} 
\approx \frac{x}{e}
$

so it converges if
$|x| < e$
and diverges if
$|x| > e$.

I don't know where your
$\sqrt{e}$
came from.